# How do I use special characters (password) on the URL when dealing with HTTP authentication?

Tags: .htaccess, http, basic-authentication

I have a directory that is protected by basic HTTP authentication.

When I access its URL, the browser asks me for the username and password.

My password is `Cw=y?qUPP+Xy`, and it works fine.

However, I would like to access it directly with the username and password on the URL.

I tried this:

`https://user:Cw=y?qUPP+Xy@example.com`, and it didn't work, for some reason google chrome returns this:

[image]

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Why would you put a username and a password in a URL? It would be exposed to anyone and everyone.

Comment: Showing passwords in the URL is unsafe and dangerous. Instead of using the GET protocol, please use POST.

Comment: Even when I'm using https:// ? 
It's on the local network anyway.

Comment: @viniciusmunich even if it's local network it's unsafe... Imagine that I'm an admin and someone is behind me (who is not an admin), when I submit the form they can simply go and check the URL and know my password. Not a good idea, right? It's like using a <input type="text"/> instead of a <input type="password"/>

Comment: The above comments are not necessarily true; The browser is supposed to parse the username and password from the URL and it crafts the the Basic Authentication header on your behalf, meaning when the request reaches the server, the credentials are not present in the URL. With that said, someone with (remote or physical) access to your device could view your URL history and steal credentials that way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to URL encode it
For example, "@" would become "%40"

But take into account that sending user and password through HTTP and/or through GET (parameters in the query string) is not a good idea... Try using POST method under HTTPS.

**I will go ahead and add my comment to this answer, for visibility:**

Even if it's local network and you are using HTTPS it's unsafe to send the password through GET... Imagine that I'm an admin and someone is behind me (who is not an admin), when I submit the form they can simply go and check the URL and know my password. Not a good idea, right?

It's like using a `<input type="text"/>` instead of a `<input type="password"/>` for the password.