# Git pull/clone with username and password in AWS Code Commit

Tags: linux, git, bash, jenkins, aws-codecommit

I need to do a git pull using https URL as an online command. this command I need to integrate in a bash script. But all the time it is asking the username and password.

The repository is in **AWS code-commit**

Comment: Read some `ssh` tutorial about public and private keys and use a `git:` URL for `git` commands

Answer (score 10):

**Try this:**

```
git clone https://username:password@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1../repos../..
```

This way worked for me for **CodeCommit** (**AWS**) repository

Comment: Note that this won't work if the password contains characters illegal for the shell currently used, like "/" and "\"

Comment: If your password contains characters illegal for the shell you can encode your password to URL (for example, @ will be %40 etc). You can see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544219/how-do-i-use-special-characters-password-on-the-url-when-dealing-with-http-aut

Answer (score 4):

Check this link: [Enter user password in command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull)

As is described perfectly in that post, you basically have three options:

1. Store the password in .netrc file (with 600 permissions). Make sure you clone the repo specifying the username in the url.
2. Clone the repo with `https://user:pass@domain/repo` . Take into account that your password will be visible in several places...
3. Use the [credential helper](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential-cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an update, AWS has released their remote git remote codecommit. With proper IAM setup, you can do oneline pulls without even passing username and passwords. This is now the recommended method by AWS. It can be setup on your local or on a container that's running in an AWS Pipeline for example.

i.e. `git clone codecommit://HelloWorldRepo myLocalHelloWorldRepo`
And then you can `git pull` as normal.

Full documentation is here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-git-remote-codecommit.html